# How to read a dataset as a dict of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to read a data file as a `dict` of nested `lists`. For example, I can construct this using

```
d = ({
     'X' :    [13,13],
     'Y' :   [17,17],
     })
```

Out:

```
{'X': [13, 13], 'Y': [17, 17]}
```

However if we read a similar dataset as a `dict` the result is:

```
d = pd.read_csv('file.csv').to_dict()
```

Out:

```
{'X': {0: 13, 1: 13},
'Y': {0: 17, 1: 17}}
```

Is there a way to re-format the second example so it uses `[]` instead of `{}`. Either when first reading a dataset or a subsequent conversion?

Comment: Can you provide some more context?

Comment: Does it make more sense now @MikeChen

Comment: @jonboy can you share some part of your csv also?

Comment: Use `.to_dict(orient='l')` where "l" stands for "list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv').to_dict(orient='list')
```

Comment: Sorry @Vineet Jain. I mean a `dict` of `lists`.

Comment: @jonboy I had updated the answer according to your question